# objective c error ImageIO: CGImageReadGetBytesAtOffset

Tags: objective-c, jpeg, cgrect

having a weird error. I have looked at all the articles on here about this error but none seem to cover the specific issue I have so I am hoping you can help

I am drawing a image from the documents directory on screen. I use the following method to place the image on the view at a certain position

```
- (CGRect)myImage:(UIImage*)image :(float)x :(float)y :(float)w :(float)h ; {
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(x,y, w, h);
[image drawInRect:imageFrame];
return imageFrame;
}
```

and call it with

```
  NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths2 objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *fileNamedata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/reportfile.jpg",
                          documentsDirectory];
  UIImage *anImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:fileNamedata];
  [self myImage:anImage1 :400 :50 :150 :49];
```

This works fine on first run but if i then run it again with a different filename say image2.jpg instead of reportfile.jpg I get the following error

```
 <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageReadGetBytesAtOffset : *** ERROR *** CGImageSource was created with data size: 54217 - current size is only: 29096
```

if I close the app and run again but this time load image2.jpg first it works fine so i know its not the images

is there a way of resetting the CGRect so it starts from fresh each time or have I got it all wrong

Many thanks for your help

Mark

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using? `imageNamed:` is for loading files from your main bundle not your documents directory

Comment: Thank you thats interesting I put the code together from various sources I'm pretty new to this any ideas what I should be using?

Comment: Thank you So Much Did some search and changed it to  UIImage *thumbNail=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileNamedata]; and it seems to work every time